# How to create a custom validation expression for html5?

Tags: html

I am creating a Contact Us form. I know how to validate know ones like Name, Number, Email but I want to create a custom validation expression of my own like this for example: 123705P

Comment: you mean you want to use custom validator ?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built-in .NET controls, then check out CustomValidators (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(v=vs.85).aspx) or RegularExpressionValidators (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Otherwise, if you want to use jQuery, then look in to the Validation plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation).